# Angular : initialisation issue of Property

Tags: angular, initialization

I am getting error of initialisation in my component.ts file

My model is

```
import { Account } from './account.model';

export interface Owner{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    dateOfBirth: string;
    address: string;

    accounts?: Account[];
}
```

And I am using it in component.ts file as :

```
export class OwnerDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  public owner: Owner;
  public errorMessage: string = '';

  constructor(private repository: RepositoryService, private router: Router, 
              private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOwnerDetails()
  }

  getOwnerDetails = () => {
    let id: string = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    let apiUrl: string = `my API url`;

    this.repository.getData(apiUrl)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.owner = res as Owner;
    })
  }

}
```

I am getting error as :
**Property 'owner' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.**

**Please note:** *I don't want to initialise it with undefined*

Please suggest how to remove this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add (!) sign after property:

```
owner!: Owner;
```

or you can disable strict typing in tsconfig.json file;

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    //   ...
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
    //   ...   }
```